# Reversing a string in C

Tags: c, string, pointers

I have developed a reverse-string program. I am wondering if there is a better way to do this, and if my code has any potential problems. I am looking to practice some advanced features of C.

```
char* reverse_string(char *str)
{
    char temp;
    size_t len = strlen(str) - 1;
    size_t i;
    size_t k = len;

    for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        temp = str[k];
        str[k] = str[i];
        str[i] = temp;
        k--;

        /* As 2 characters are changing place for each cycle of the loop
           only traverse half the array of characters */
        if(k == (len / 2))
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This question is similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/219420/how-would-you-improve-this-algorithm-c-string-reversal

Comment: strlen(str)-1 will underflow if the string is empty

Comment: We can use i < len/2 inside the for loop ``     for(i = 0; i < len/2; i++)
    {
        temp = str[k];
        str[k] = str[i];
        str[i] = temp;
        k--;
    } ``

Answer (score 73, accepted):

If you want to practice advanced features of C, how about pointers?
We can toss in macros and xor-swap for fun too!

```
#include <string.h> // for strlen()

// reverse the given null-terminated string in place
void inplace_reverse(char * str)
{
  if (str)
  {
    char * end = str + strlen(str) - 1;

    // swap the values in the two given variables
    // XXX: fails when a and b refer to same memory location
#   define XOR_SWAP(a,b) do\
    {\
      a ^= b;\
      b ^= a;\
      a ^= b;\
    } while (0)

    // walk inwards from both ends of the string, 
    // swapping until we get to the middle
    while (str < end)
    {
      XOR_SWAP(*str, *end);
      str++;
      end--;
    }
#   undef XOR_SWAP
  }
}
```

A **pointer** (e.g. `char *`, read from right-to-left as a *pointer to a `char`*) is a data type in C that is used
to refer to location in memory of another value.  In this case,
the location where a `char` is stored.  We can *dereference*
pointers by prefixing them with an `*`, which gives us the value
stored at that location.  So the value stored at `str` is `*str`.

We can do simple arithmetic with pointers.  When we increment (or decrement)
a pointer, we simply move it to refer to the next (or previous)
memory location for that type of value.  Incrementing pointers of
different types may move the pointer by a different number of
bytes because different values have different byte sizes in C.

Here, we use one pointer to refer to the first unprocessed
`char` of the string (`str`) and another to refer to the last (`end`).
We swap their values (`*str` and `*end`), and move the pointers
inwards to the middle of the string.  Once `str >= end`, either
they both point to the same `char`, which means our original string had an
odd length (and the middle `char` doesn't need to be reversed), or
we've processed everything.

To do the swapping, I've defined a **macro**.  Macros are text substitution
done by the C preprocessor.  They are very different from functions,
and it's important to know the difference.  When you call a function,
the function operates on a copy of the values you give it.  When you call
a macro, it simply does a textual substitution - so the arguments you give
it are used directly.

Since I only used the `XOR_SWAP` macro once, it was probably overkill to define it,
but it made more clear what I was doing.  After the C preprocessor expands the macro,
the while loop looks like this:

```
    while (str < end)
    {
      do { *str ^= *end; *end ^= *str; *str ^= *end; } while (0);
      str++;
      end--;
    }
```

Note that the macro arguments show up once for each time they're used in the 
macro definition.   This can be very useful - but can also break your code
if used incorrectly.  For example, if I had compressed the increment/decrement
instructions and the macro call into a single line, like

```
      XOR_SWAP(*str++, *end--);
```

Then this would expand to

```
      do { *str++ ^= *end--; *end-- ^= *str++; *str++ ^= *end--; } while (0);
```

Which has *triple* the increment/decrement operations, and doesn't actually
do the swap it's supposed to do.

While we're on the subject, you should know what **xor** (`^`) means.  It's a basic
arithmetic operation - like addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, except
it's not usually taught in elementary school.  It combines two integers bit by bit
- like addition, but we don't care about the carry-overs.  `1^1 = 0`, `1^0 = 1`,
`0^1 = 1`, `0^0 = 0`.

A well known trick is to use xor to swap two values.  This works because of three basic
properties of xor: `x ^ 0 = x`, `x ^ x = 0` and `x ^ y = y ^ x` for all values `x` and `y`.  So say we have two
variables `a` and `b` that are initially storing two values
`va` and `vb`.

```
  // initially:
  // a == va
  // b == vb
  a ^= b;
  // now: a == va ^ vb
  b ^= a;
  // now: b == vb ^ (va ^ vb)
  //        == va ^ (vb ^ vb)
  //        == va ^ 0
  //        == va
  a ^= b;
  // now: a == (va ^ vb) ^ va
  //        == (va ^ va) ^ vb
  //        == 0 ^ vb
  //        == vb
```

So the values are swapped.  This does have one bug - when `a` and `b` are the same variable:

```
  // initially:
  // a == va
  a ^= a;
  // now: a == va ^ va
  //        == 0
  a ^= a;
  // now: a == 0 ^ 0
  //        == 0
  a ^= a;
  // now: a == 0 ^ 0
  //        == 0
```

Since we `str < end`, this never happens in the above code, so we're okay.

While we're concerned about correctness we should check our edge cases.  The `if (str)` line should make sure we weren't given a `NULL` pointer for string.  What about the empty string `""`?  Well `strlen("") == 0`, so we'll initialize `end` as `str - 1`, which means that the `while (str < end)` condition is never true, so we don't do anything.  Which is correct.

There's a bunch of C to explore.  Have fun with it!

**Update:** [mmw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/92202/mmw) brings up a good point, which is you do have to be slightly careful how you invoke this, as it does operate in-place.

```
 char stack_string[] = "This string is copied onto the stack.";
 inplace_reverse(stack_string);
```

This works fine, since `stack_string` is an array, whose contents are initialized to the given string constant.  However

```
 char * string_literal = "This string is part of the executable.";
 inplace_reverse(string_literal);
```

Will cause your code to flame and die at runtime.  That's because `string_literal` merely points to the string that is stored as part of your executable - which is normally memory that you are not allowed to edit by the OS.  In a happier world, your compiler would know this, and cough an error when you tried to compile, telling you that `string_literal` needs to be of type `char const *` since you can't modify the contents.  However, this is not the world my compiler lives in.

There are some hacks you could try to make sure that some memory is on the stack or in the heap (and is therefore editable), but they're not necessarily portable, and it could be pretty ugly.  However, I'm more than happy to throw responsibility for this to the function invoker.  I've told them that this function does in place memory manipulation, it's their responsibility to give me an argument that allows that.

Comment: Well, I check for that with the if(str) line - and since I'm reversing in place, I only have to worry about the input.

Comment: Ah.  I see what you mean now.  You mean I need to make sure that the argument is not for a `char const *` that's part of the binary.  This is true of every inplace reversal and should be noted.  If you had said `char s[] = "Dante Alighieri est né";`, then that would be fine, since it'd be on the stack.  Unfortunately, I don't think there is a portable check for this.  In an ideal world, the compiler would have required your example to be `char const * s = "..."` since the RHS is non-modifiable.

Comment: Perhaps you'd care to enlighten us as to why xor swap is actually a good idea? It's generally slower than the "plain" version, it's harder to read and it fails spectacularly if you try to swap an address with itself.

Comment: Both accurate points; however my goal here was not to write the most efficient code, but just to have an excuse to write about various C features and Cisms  Xor swap is good to know about, if only to recognize it.

Answer (score 27):

Just a rearrangement, and safety check. I also removed your non-used return type. I think this is a safe and clean as it gets:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void reverse_string(char *str)
{
    /* skip null */
    if (str == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    /* skip empty string */
    if (*str == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    /* get range */
    char *start = str;
    char *end = start + strlen(str) - 1; /* -1 for \0 */
    char temp;

    /* reverse */
    while (end > start)
    {
        /* swap */
        temp = *start;
        *start = *end;
        *end = temp;

        /* move */
        ++start;
        --end;
    }
}


int main(void)
{
    char s1[] = "Reverse me!";
    char s2[] = "abc";
    char s3[] = "ab";
    char s4[] = "a";
    char s5[] = "";

    reverse_string(0);

    reverse_string(s1);
    reverse_string(s2);
    reverse_string(s3);
    reverse_string(s4);
    reverse_string(s5);

    printf("%s\n", s1);
    printf("%s\n", s2);
    printf("%s\n", s3);
    printf("%s\n", s4);
    printf("%s\n", s5);

    return 0;
}
```

Edited so that end will not point to a possibly bad memory location when strlen is 0.

Comment: I'm going to be a pedantic jerk here.  There's something unsafe in this function:  the line "char* end = start + strlen(str) - 1;" results in undefined behavior when strlen(str)==0.

Comment: Heh, I thought of that after I posted but I was just gonna hope nobody saw :>

Though this isn't undefined, is it? It will point to a bad memory location, which is bad, but it's still well defined, yes?

In any case I've updated my post for more safety. Keep telling me if there's more :) I strive for correctness.

Comment: While this is unlikely to be an actual problem in most environments, it's undefined behavior by the standard.  The standard allows pointer arithmetic to result in pointers within the array or to one past the last element of the array (in this last case the pointer is not allowed to be dereferenced, of course).

Comment: Ah, ok, good to know, thanks. 'Cept now you made my code uglier :P

Comment: Sorry about uglifying the code...  since the strrev() routine is so often used in interviews, this little bit is something I always look for. I don't hold it against anyone (if that's the worst problem the function had, I don't think there's much to worry about), but pointing it out it can spur further conversation which gives additional insight.

Comment: I doubted you @Michael Burr - so I looked it up and you're right - section 6.5.6: "If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object, the evaluation shall not produce an overﬂow; otherwise, the behavior is undeﬁned."  OTOH, I've never been on a compiler where arbitrary subtraction was an issue.

Comment: Like I said, it's unlikely to be a real problem - the one that I can think of off the top of my head is the good old, obsolete, segmented MS-DOS architecture.  If your pointer happened to be at offset 0 of the segment, then this would cause a problem.

Comment: There are plenty of small embedded platforms where you can't count on a nice linear memory model. On a PC this isn't going to be an issue (unless you're running DOS), but your code won't be portable. It's generally best to don't do pointer arithmetics outside the bounds of your array.

Answer (score 18):

You can put your `(len/2)` test in the for loop:

```
for(i = 0,k=len-1 ; i < (len/2); i++,k--)
{
        temp = str[k];
        str[k] = str[i];
        str[i] = temp;

}
```

Comment: Nice one +1. Could also write a SWAP Macro?

Comment: @CoderGuy: `k` is from the code in the question - it's an index starting at the last character of the string moving toward the beginning of the string.  There's still a bug that isn't handled - if the length of the string is `0` the reverse function will perform incorrectly.  This answer doesn't properly handle that scenario. I'd probably add something like the equivalent of `if (strlen(str) == 0) return;` at the start of the function.

Comment: @MichaelBurr so I have to pass trough the length of the string

Answer (score 14):

This complete program shows how I would do it. Keep in mind I was writing C when most of you whippersnappers were a glint in your mothers eyes so it's old-school, do-the-job, long-var-names-are-for-wimps. Fix that if you wish, I'm more interested in the correctness of the code.

It handles NULLs, empty strings and all string sizes. I haven't tested it with strings of maximum size (max(size_t)) but it should work, and if you're handling strings that big, you're insane anyway :-)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *revStr (char *str) {
    char tmp, *src, *dst;
    size_t len;
    if (str != NULL)
    {
        len = strlen (str);
        if (len > 1) {
            src = str;
            dst = src + len - 1;
            while (src < dst) {
                tmp = *src;
                *src++ = *dst;
                *dst-- = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
    return str;
}

char *str[] = {"", "a", "ab", "abc", "abcd", "abcde"};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i;
    char s[10000];
    for (i=0; i < sizeof(str)/sizeof(str[0]); i++) {
        strcpy (s, str[i]);
        printf ("'%s' -> '%s'\n", str[i], revStr(s));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output of that is:

```
'' -> ''
'a' -> 'a'
'ab' -> 'ba'
'abc' -> 'cba'
'abcd' -> 'dcba'
'abcde' -> 'edcba'
```

Comment: You may want to refer to the little conversation in GMan's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784417/c-reverse-a-string/784455#784455

Comment: Thanks, @MB, although that will never occur in practice, I guess we have to follow the standard. Updated to handle empty strings, and optimized to handle 1-character strings at the same time.

Comment: But you code just doesn't work. It gives same string w/o last char.

Comment: _Absolutely_ right, @Oleg, I was using `strlen (src)` (which was uninitialised) rather than `strlen (str)` - fixed now. Thanks for pointing that out. For someone "more interested in the correctness of the code", you'd think I would have tested it a bit :-)

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
reverse_string(NULL);
reverse_string("");
```

Comment: All of the POSIX functions are undefined for NULL, strlen, strcat etc. It should be the responsibility of the caller to check for NULL, not the function. Garbage in garbage out. Or in this case, garbage in then segfault.

Comment: "" is [const char*], not [char*] => you cannot reverse constants in place.

Answer (score 6):

You could change your for loop declaration to make the code shorter:

```
char* reverse_string(char *str)
{
    char temp;
    size_t len = strlen(str) - 1;
    size_t stop = len/2;
    size_t i,k;

    for(i = 0, k = len; i < stop; i++, k--)
    {
        temp = str[k];
        str[k] = str[i];
        str[i] = temp;
    }
    return str;
}
```

Comment: @mmw - why do you think it will crash?

Comment: @Ben: why not: for (i = 0, k = len; i < k; i++, k--) ...?

Answer (score 6):

Does nobody use pointers anymore?

```
void inplace_rev( char * s ) {
  char t, *e = s + strlen(s);
  while ( --e > s ) { t = *s;*s++=*e;*e=t; }
}
```

EDIT: Sorry, just noticed the above XOR example...

Comment: What to do if you have const char*?

Answer (score 5):

```
void reverse(char *s)
{
  char *end,temp;
  end = s;
  while(*end != '\0'){
    end++;
  }
  end--;  //end points to last letter now
  for(;s<end;s++,end--){
    temp = *end;
    *end = *s;
    *s = temp; 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't see a return statement, and you are changing the input string, which may be a problem for the programmer. You may want the input string to be immutable.

Also, this may be picky, but len/2 should be calculated only one time, IMO.

Other than that, it will work, as long as you take care of the problem cases mentioned by rossfabricant.

Answer (score 3):

```
/* Author: Siken Dongol */
#include <stdio.h>

int strLength(char *input) {
    int i = 0;
    while(input[i++]!='\0');
    return --i;
}

int main()
{
    char input[] = "Siken Man Singh Dongol";

    int len = strLength(input);
    char output[len];

    int index = 0;
    while(len >= 0) {
        output[index++] = input[--len];
    }

    printf("%s\n",input);
    printf("%s\n",output);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
rev {
int len = strlen(str)-1;
for ( int i =0; i< len/2 ; i++ ) {
        char t = str[i];
        str[i] = str[len-i];
        str[len-i] = t;
        }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my shot. I avoid swapping just by using the standard `strcpy` pattern:

```
char *string_reverse(char *dst, const char *src)
{
    if (src == NULL) return NULL;

    const char *src_start = src;
    char *dst_end = dst + strlen(src);
    *dst_end = '\0';

    while ((*--dst_end = *src_start++)) { ; }

    return dst;
}
```

[and here a running example](http://ideone.com/KREi2r).

Answer (score 2):

```
bool reverse_string(char* str) {
    if(str == NULL){
        return false;
    }
    if(strlen(str) < 2){
        return false;
    }
    
    char* first = str;
    char* last = str + strlen(str) - 1; // Minus 1 accounts for Index offset
    char temp;

    do{
        temp = *first;
        *first = *last;
        *last = temp;
    }
    while (++first < --last); // Update Pointer Addresses and check for equality

    return true;
}
```

This solution is based on GManNickG's post with a few modifications. The initial logical statement may be dangerous if !str is not evaluated before the strlen operation (For a NULL ptr). This wasn't the case with my compiler. I thought I would add this code because its a nice example of a do-while loop.

Answer (score 2):

The code looks unnecessarily complicated. Here is my version:

```
void strrev(char* str) { 
    size_t len = strlen(str);
    char buf[len]; 

    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) { 
        buf[i] = str[len - 1 - i]; 
    }; 

    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) { 
        str[i] = buf[i]; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you say you want to get fancy, perhaps you'll want to exchange your characters using an [XOR swap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm).

Comment: Does the xor trick even work for signed chars on every system? 32-bit chars?

Comment: It works as long as you are not swapping with the same location. But it's much slower than just using a temp variable on most platforms anyway.

Comment: @Arafangion - XOR swap uses bitwise operations. The end result of an XOR swap is that the two variables swapped will end up with the same bit values they started with, but swapped. Same bit values = same values, signed or unsigned, 8-, 16- or 32-bit. Maybe if you swap a signed and an unsigned, or different sized characters, it won't work - but what will in that case?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than breaking half-way through, you should simply shorten your loop.

```
size_t length = strlen(str);
size_t i;

for (i = 0; i < (length / 2); i++)
{
    char temp = str[length - i - 1];
    str[length - i - 1] = str[i];
    str[i] = temp;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() 
{
    char *data = "hello world";
    int length=strlen(data);
    char bytes[length];
    int n=0;
    while(n<=length)
    {
       bytes[n] = data[length-n-1];
       n++;
    }
    printf("%s\n", bytes);
    return 0;   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()    
{

    char string[100];
    int i;

    printf("Enter a string:\n");
    gets(string);
    printf("\n");
    for(i=strlen(string)-1;i>-1;i--)

    printf("%c",string[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Here is my shot which will handle all the cases 
char *p ="KDLAKDADKADAD"
char p[] = "lammdlamldaldladadada"
also empty string 

#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>enter code here
#include<stdlib.h>
char *string_reverse(char *p);
int main()
{

        char *p = " Deepak@klkaldkaldkakdoroorerr";
        char *temp = string_reverse(p);
        printf("%s", temp);
}
char *  string_reverse( char *p )
{

        if(*p == '\0')
        {
                printf("No charecters are present \n");
                return 0;
        }
        int count = strlen(p)+1;
        int mid = strlen(p)/2;
        char *q  = (char *)malloc(count * sizeof(char));
        if( q )
        {
                strcpy(q,p);
                char *begin,*end,temp;
                begin = q ;
                end = q+strlen(p)-1  ;
                int i = 0;
                while( i < mid/2 )
                {
                        temp = *end;
                        *end = *begin;
                        *begin = temp;
                        begin++;
                        end--;
                        i++;
                }
                return q;
        }
        else
        {

                printf("Memory Not allocated ");
        }
        free(q);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My two cents:

```c
/* Reverses n characters of a string and adds a '\0' at the end */
void strnrev (char *txt, size_t len) {
    size_t idx;
    for (idx = len >> 1; idx > 0; idx--) {
        txt[len] = txt[idx - 1];
        txt[idx - 1] = txt[len - idx];
        txt[len - idx] = txt[len];
    }
    txt[len] = '\0';
}

/* Reverses a null-terminated string */
void strrev (char *txt) {
    size_t len = 0;
    while (txt[len++]);
    strnrev(txt, --len);
}
```

**Test #1** – `strrev()`:

```c
char string[] = "Hello world!";
strrev(string);
printf("%s\n", string); // Displays "!dlrow olleH"
```

**Test #2** – `strnrev()`:

```c
char string[] = "Hello world!";
strnrev(string, 5);
printf("%s\n", string); // Displays "olleH"
```

Answer (score 1):

easy and simple code xD

```
void strrev (char s[]) {

int i;
int dim = strlen (s);
char l;

for (i = 0; i < dim / 2; i++) {
    l = s[i];
    s[i] = s[dim-i-1];
    s[dim-i-1] = l;
    }

}
```

Comment: very simple to understand and low cost

Answer (score 1):

You can try this pointer arithmetic:

```
void revString(char *s)
{
  char *e = s; while(*e){ e++; } e--;
  while(e > s){ *s ^= *e; *e ^= *s; *s++ ^= *e--; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can actually do something like this:

```
#include <string.h>

void reverse(char *);

int main(void){
 char name[7] = "walter";
 reverse(name);
 printf("%s", name);
}

void reverse(char *s) {
  size_t len = strlen(s);
  char *a = s;
  char *b = &s[(int)len - 1];
  char tmp;
  for (; a < b; ++a, --b) {
    tmp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = tmp;
  }
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 1):

Made a tiny program that accomplishes that:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char str[8192] = "string"; // string
    size_t len = strlen(str)-1; // get string length and reduce 1

    while(len+1 > 0) // Loop for every character on string
    {
        printf("%c",str[len--]); // Print string reversed and reducing len by one
    }
    return 0; // Quit program

}
```

Explanation:
We take the length of the string, and then we start looping by the last position until we arrive to index 0 quit program.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do with the help of pointer in very few steps :

1. first point a pointer to the last char of the string
2. read the content pointed by the pointer in reverse order

   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <string.h>

   ```
        int main()
        {
            char str[] = "This is an example";
            char *p = str + strlen(str); /* point to the end of the string */
            p--; /* points to the last char of the string */

            for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++, p--)
            {
               printf("%c", *p);
            }

            return 0;
        }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

That's a good question [ant2009](https://stackoverflow.com/users/70942/ant2009). You can use a standalone function to reverse the string. The code is...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_CHARACTERS 99

int main( void );
int strlen( char __str );

int main() {
    char *str[ MAX_CHARACTERS ];
    char *new_string[ MAX_CHARACTERS ];
    int i, j;

    printf( "enter string: " );
    gets( *str );

    for( i = 0; j = ( strlen( *str ) - 1 ); i < strlen( *str ), j > -1; i++, j-- ) {
        *str[ i ] = *new_string[ j ];
    }
    printf( "Reverse string is: %s", *new_string" );
    return ( 0 );
}

int strlen( char __str[] ) {
    int count;
    for( int i = 0; __str[ i ] != '\0'; i++ ) {
         ++count;
    }
    return ( count );
}
```

Comment: Never, never, never user `gets`. It is so insecure and so vulnerable to buffer overflow, it has been removed from the C11 library. I recommend a quick change to using `fgets` and trimming the trailing `'\n'`. Also note that variable names preceded by two underscores are generally reserved for use by the compiler...

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way, just use this function, see the usage.
function :

```
char *reversed(char *string) {
    int len = strlen(string);
    char newstr[256];
    for (int i = 0; i <= len-1; i++) {
        newstr[i] = string[(len-1)-i];
    }
    string = newstr;
    return string;
}
```

usage :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


char *reversed(char *string);
int main()
{
    char test[] = "test";
    char *res = reversed(test);
    printf("%s\n", res);

    return 0;
}
char *reversed(char *string) {
    int len = strlen(string);
    char newstr[256];
    for (int i = 0; i <= len-1; i++) {
        newstr[i] = string[(len-1)-i];
    }
    string = newstr;
    return string;
}
```

do not forget to assign it to a pointer. `char *res = reversed(test)`