# Byte order conversion in cpp

Tags: c++, hex, endianness

I am trying to solve a problem.
I have a char * SERIAL_HEX = 5F6D1F7F 
But my code is expecting the SERIAL_HEX in reverse order.
Like SERIAL_HEX = 7F1F6D5F

So its reversing the hex digits..How can i achieve this in c++ ?
Any pointers will help me!
Thanks,

Comment: What have you tried ? Did you tried to just [reverse hex string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784417/reversing-a-string-in-c) ?

Comment: yes thats what i want to do. reverse the hex string. Currently the hex string stores the serial number of certificate. and i want to reverse this serial number as in the example i gave earlier

Answer (score 1):

You have (at least) 2 possibilities:

- convert each character pair to a byte, reverse the resulting string with `std::reverse()` and convert each byte back to its hex-representation
- swap each character pair with the one counting from the end.