# loop to reverse string in C

Tags: c, arrays, function, char, reverse

So I've looked around on SO and can't find code that answers my question.  I have written a function that is supposed to reverse a string as input in cmd-line.  Here is the function:

```
void reverse (char string[]) {
    int x;
    int i = 0;
    char line[strlen(string)];

    for (x = strlen(string) - 1; x > 0; x--) {
        char tmp = string[x];
        line[i] = tmp;
        i++;
    }
    string = line;
}
```

When I call my reverse() function, the string stays the same.  i.e., 'abc' remains 'abc'

If more info is needed or question is inappropriate, let me know.

Thanks!!

Comment: I never use the `char string[]` syntax for arguments, since it makes it not  obvious that `string` is actually a pointer. (Edit: I mean to the person reading or writing the code; the computer doesn't care)

Comment: in order to "make it obvious" should it be:  char* string[] ?

Comment: It would be `char* string`. Next question: Do you know why `void f(int x) {x = 7;} int main() {int y = 5; f(y); printf("%d\n", y); return 0;}` prints 5 and not 7?

Comment: more generally: what happens if you return a pointer to local variable?

Comment: i'm really new to this so go easy on me but....is it because y points to a value and not the address of  ?

Comment: doesn't the pointer return the address of the variable and NOT the value?

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784417/reversing-a-string-in-c

Comment: I know you asked about C, but in case you're open to C++: `std::reverse(string.begin(),string.end())`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're declaring your `line` array one `char` shorter remember the `null` at the end.

Another point, it should be `for (x = strlen(string) - 1; x >= 0; x--)` since you need to copy the character at `0`.

```
void reverse (char string[]) {
    int x;
    int i = 0;
    char line[strlen(string) + 1];

    for (x = strlen(string) - 1; x >= 0; x--) {
        char tmp = string[x];
        line[i] = tmp;
        i++;
    }

    for(x = 0; x < strlen(string); x++)
    {
        string[x] = line[x];
    }
}
```

Note that this function will cause an apocalypse when passed an empty string or a string literal (as Bobby Sacamano said).

Suggestion you can probably do: `void reverse(char source[], char[] dest)` and do checks if the source string is empty.

Comment: In the original code it the `line` array (`char line[strlen(string)]`)was declared on the stack not on the heap, therefore it disappears after the function call leaving `string` pointing nowhere.

Comment: @BobbySacamano Ah yes, that was my bad. You are correct about `string = line` since `string` was indeed passed on the stack. Got confused by `char string[]`, was never used to passing arrays. Cheers.

Comment: One last question John...what does adding the +1 to char line[strlen(string) + 1]  do exactly?  Is that what gets the char at 0?

Comment: For example let's say we are passing "message" to `reverse`, that means `strlen()` will return `7`, but C strings should be null terminated so there has to be a `0` at the very last character so you need one last slot for it (therefore `char line[8]`).

Comment: @JohnMarkCaguicla does the standard mandate that the '\0' character is always 0?

Comment: @BobbySacamano No it does not, I just used it for the sake of explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The last line in your code does nothing
`string = line;`

Parameters are passed by value, so if you change their value, that is only local to the function. Pointers are the value of the address of memory they are pointing to. If you want to modify the pointer that the function was passed, you need to take a pointer to that pointer.

Here is a short example of how you could do that.

```
void reverse (char **string) {
    char line = malloc(strlen(*string) + 1);
    //automatic arrays are deallocated once the function ends
    //so line needs to be dynamically or statically allocated

   // do something to line

    *string = line;
}
```

The obvious issue with this is that you can initialize the string with static memory, then this method will replace the static memory with dynamic memory, and then you'll have to free the dynamic memory. There's nothing functionally wrong with that, it's just a bit dangerous, since accidentally freeing the string literal is illegal.

```
char *test = "hello";
reverse(test);
free(test); //this is pretty scary
```

Also, if test was allocated as dynamic memory, the pointer to it would be lost and then it would become a memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your answer is almost correct.  You don't actually need an extra slot for the null character in line.  You just need two minor changes:

- Change the assignment statement at the bottom of the procedure to a memcpy.
- Change the loop condition to <-

So, your correct code is this:

```
void reverse (char string[]) {
  int x;
  int i = 0;
  char line[strlen(string)];

  for (x = strlen(string) - 1; x >= 0; x--) {
    char tmp = string[x];
    line[i] = tmp;
    i++;
  }
  memcpy(string, line, sizeof(char) * strlen(line));
}
```

Comment: can you explain what memcpy() does?

Comment: it copies memory from the second operand to the first operand, for the number of bytes specified by the third operand. `sizeof(char) == 1` always, in case you see string examples missing the sizeof. With other data types you need sizeof.

Comment: memcpy is a standard c function that copies the data from the 2nd parameter (the source) into the first parameter (the destination).  The amount of data in bytes is specified in the 3rd parameter.  In the code above it will copy the characters from the variable "line" into the memory location of the variable "string".

Comment: If someone calls reverse with a string literal, that will break things, btw.

Comment: Right.  That will cause a crash.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to reverse a string, you first must decide whether you want to reverse a copy of the string, or reverse the string in-situ (in place). Since you asked about this in 'C' context, assume you mean to change the existing string (reverse the existing string) and make a copy of the string in the calling function if you want to preserve the original.

You will need the string library

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
```

Array indexing works, and this version takes that approach,

```
/* this first version uses array indexing */
char*
streverse_a(char string[])
{
    int len; /*how big is your string*/
    int ndx; /*because 'i' is hard to search for*/
    char tmp; /*hold character to swap*/
    if(!string) return(string); /*avoid NULL*/
    if( (len=strlen(string)) < 2 ) return(string); /*one and done*/
    for( ndx=0; ndx<len/2; ndx++ ) {
        tmp=string[ndx];
        string[ndx]=string[len-1-ndx];
        string[len-1-ndx]=tmp;
    }
    return(string);
}
```

But you can do the same with pointers,

```
/* this is how K&R would write the function with pointers */
char*
streverse(char* sp)
{
    int len, ndx; /*how big is your string */
    char tmp, *bp, *ep; /*pointers to begin/end, swap temporary*/
    if(!sp) return(sp); /*avoid NULL*/
    if( (len=strlen(bp=sp)) < 2 ) return(sp); /*one and done*/
    for( ep=bp+len-1; bp<ep; bp++, ep-- ) {
        tmp=*bp; *bp=*ep; *ep=tmp; /*swap*/
    }
    return(sp);
}
```

*(No, really, the compiler does not charge less for returning void.)*

And because you ***always*** test your code,

```
char s[][100] = {
    "", "A", "AB", "ABC", "ABCD", "ABCDE",
    "hello, world", "goodbye, cruel world", "pwnz0r3d", "enough"
};

int
main()
{
    /* suppose your string is declared as 'a' */
    char a[100];
    strcpy(a,"reverse string");

    /*make a copy of 'a', declared the same as a[]*/
    char b[100];
    strcpy(b,a);
    streverse_a(b);
    printf("a:%s, r:%s\n",a,b);

    /*duplicate 'a'*/
    char *rp = strdup(a);
    streverse(rp);
    printf("a:%s, r:%s\n",a,rp);
    free(rp);

    int ndx;
    for( ndx=0; ndx<10; ++ndx ) {
        /*make a copy of 's', declared the same as s[]*/
        char b[100];
        strcpy(b,s[ndx]);
        streverse_a(b);
        printf("s:%s, r:%s\n",s[ndx],b);

        /*duplicate 's'*/
        char *rp = strdup(s[ndx]);
        streverse(rp);
        printf("s:%s, r:%s\n",s[ndx],rp);
        free(rp);
    }
}
```