# Reveres the string doesn't work in C

Tags: c

I have a reversing-a-string program below which didn't work. 
A line "str[start] = str[end];" in the while loop caused it to end prematurely
(it's marked down below).

### Any pointers appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int end, start;
    char temp;
    char* str = "hello";
    start = 0;
    end = strlen(str) - 1;

    while(end > start)
    {
        temp = str[start];
        str[start] = str[end];   // <------------- This line caused issue
        str[end] = temp;
        start++; end--;
    }

    // print out string
    int i = 0;
    while (str[i])
        printf("%c\n", str[i++]);
}
```

Comment: Change `char* str = "hello";` to `char str[] = "hello";`.

Comment: I think you mean `#include <stdio.h>`! This is what you need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784417/reversing-a-string-in-c

Comment: Thanks much, the answers helped me answer my question.
(char* is immutable; whereas char [] is mutable.)

Comment: Does this actually compile for you? What compiler are you using? And are you sure you're writing C?