# When I try to print the string inputted by the user in the console and then print the same inputted string;the first word gets omittedl. How do i fix?

Tags: c

As you can see in the above mentioned title , I don't know if there is something I am doing wrong . I have just started learning c . Please help me with the code.

```
#include <stdio.h> //code in c language.
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    char str[20];
    printf("Enter the string:");
    scanf("%s",&str);
    gets(str);
    printf("The string is: %s \n",str);
    printf("The reverse string is : %s",strrev(str));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First, it's better if you go through small examples first understanding how array works and input into them. Second, using both `scanf` and `get` together makes no sense. So read up on those, also might want to read why not to use `gets`.

Comment: The reason your `gets` gets skipped is that it consumes the newline left over from the previous `scanf`. Note that the `gets` function is [dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/3049655) and should not be used. Also, you should remove the ampersand from your `scanf` as the name of an array is converted to a pointer to its first element automatically

Comment: Thanks for the help. I didn't really knew what gets() does and used it . Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the **complete** *string* from `stdin`, its recommended to use `fgets` like follows:

```
#include <stdio.h> //code in c language.
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char str[20];
    printf("Enter the string:");

    /* strtok removes trailing newline character from fgets() */
    strtok(fgets(str, 20, stdin), "\n");
    printf("The string is: %s \n", str);

    /* error is still present here */
    printf("The reverse string is : %s", strrev(str));
    return 0;
}
```

The above should answer your question although `strrev()` is currently causing an error!

Here is a link to a previous stackOverflow question on successfully reversing a string: [Reversing a string in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784417/reversing-a-string-in-c)

Comment: I think you should upvote and mark as accepted if my answer solves your issue IMHO :)