# Why are unwanted characters being added to the string I'm trying to reverse?

Tags: c, string

I'm brand new to C. I've been going through exercises in a book I found, and have been having a lot of trouble understand strings. For this program, I'm simply trying to reverse a string that is read from user input.

The code I currently have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 300

void reverseStr(char *str, int len){
    int i;
    char temp[len];
    for (i = len; i >= 0; i--){
        strncat(temp, &str[i], 1);
    }
    strcpy(str, temp);
}
int main(){
    char *buffer;
    size_t buffsize = 32;
    size_t characters;
    while (characters != 1){
        buffer = (char *)malloc(buffsize * sizeof(char));
        if ( buffer = NULL){
            perror("Unable to allocate buffer");
            exit(1); 
        }

        printf("Type something: ");
        characters = getline(&buffer, &buffsize, stdin);
        printf("%zu characters were read.\n", characters);
        printf("You typed: %s", buffer);
        reverseStr(buffer, buffsize);
        printf("backwards: %s\n", buffer);
    }

}
```

What I currently have **does** reverse the string, but it also prepends a bunch of, what I assume to be null characters in the beginning.

Sample input/output:

```
Type something: sdf
4 characters were read.
You typed: sdf
backwards: 0s����
fds
```

As you can see, `sdf` does return `fds` as it should, but with extra unwanted characters prepended to it.

To further add to my confusion, I have gotten this to work properly before in another program I made.

```
/* This should be compiled with -ansi flag */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX 3000

void reverseStr(char str[MAX], int len);
int getline(char s[], int lim);

int main(){
    /* Read below on why we use a char array instead of a string, 
     * it's very important we understand this */
    char line[MAX];
    int len = strlen(line)-1;

    while((len=getline(line, MAX))>0){
        len = strlen(line)-1;
        reverseStr(line, len);
        printf("%s\n", line);
    }
}

void reverseStr(char str[MAX], int len){
    int i;
    char temp[len];
    for (i = len; i >= 0; i--){
        strncat(temp, &str[i], 1);
    }
    strcpy(str, temp);
}

int getline(char s[],int lim){
  int i,c;

  for(i=0;i<lim-1 && (c=getchar())!=EOF && c!='\n';++i)
    s[i] = c;
  if( c == '\n')
  {
    s[i]=c;
    ++i;
  }
  s[i]='\0';
  
  return i;
}
```

Output of second program:

```
sdf

fds
sdfsdfsdf

fdsfdsfds
```

The `getline()` in the second program is taken straight from the book. I'm guessing this must be an old, deprecated way of doing things though? It appears to be a built-in function in later versions of C.

Comment: Variables need to be initialized before you use them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reversing a string in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784417/reversing-a-string-in-c)

Comment: "_This should be compiled with -ansi flag_" - For gcc, that means C90. Are you sure you want that? C17(18) is available too via `-std=c17` (or `-std=c18`). C90 is 27 years older than C17.

Comment: @TedLyngmo That solution worked for me, thank you. Perhaps my approach to the problem just isn't a good one. That solution is a bit tough for me to understand though however. Also I will note not to use ansi, thank you for mentioning that.

Comment: I see some close votes as a duplicate, but I appreciate that you provided a complete example and explained your expectations and actual results and even an alternate approach.  Well done asking.  Be aware, this may be closed as a duplicate only because the title looks like you're just asking how to reverse a string which is a well known thing.  A better title may be "Why are there unwanted characters being added to the string I'm trying to reverse?"

Comment: I was afraid it would, thank you though. I've already gotten great answers so no problem if it does!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can more easily be done by just copying in the characters in reverse, then adding a NULL terminating byte at the end.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void reverse_string(char *str, char *rev_str) {
    int j = 0, i;
    for (i = strlen(str) - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        rev_str[j++] = str[i];
    }
    rev_str[j] = '\0';
}

int main() {
    char *str = "123456789";
    char rev_str[strlen(str)];
    printf("%s\n", str);
    reverse_string(str, rev_str);
    printf("%s\n", rev_str);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
123456789
987654321
```

Comment: Ah, I can't believe I didn't think about this. I just read about the null terminator characters haha. This solution was much easier for me to follow, thank you!

Comment: ... and if you want reversing in-place: [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/o8ze5jM6G)

Comment: @TedLyngmo Hmm, so I notice that that solution gives me a segmentation fault when I use a char pointer instead of a char array. Why is that?

Comment: @Hoswoo Because it's not really a `char*` but a `const char*`. You can't change string literals, like `reverse_string("change me");`. You can define a `char*` to such a string literal (which is bonkers) but actually changing them makes the program have _undefined behavior_. Always define them with `const` to prevent segfaults and to get compilation errors instead: `const char *foo = "Hello world;"` instead of `char *foo = "Hello world";`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I see, I will keep note of that.