# how to reverse string in array in C

Tags: c, function, char, reverse, c-strings

I have exercise to use for loop to initialization 1 string array from **A to Z** and then **Z to A**.

I was successful to print from **A to Z** but print **Z to A** not working. So i need to help in this code.

```
char *problem58()
{
    char temp, *result = (char *)malloc(52 * sizeof(char));
    int left = 0, right = 52 - 1;

    for (char i = 'A'; i <= 'Z'; i++)
    {
        result[left] = i;
        printf("%c", i);
        left++;
    }
    // this is my idea to reverse this string
    for (int i = left; i < right; i++)
    {
        temp = result[left];
        result[left] = result[right];
        result[right] = temp;
        printf("%c", result[right]);
        right--;
    }
    return result;
}
```

line code run in terminal: `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZSW\:C=cepSmoC`

Comment: possibly similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784417/reversing-a-string-in-c

Comment: `result[left] = result[right];` - what have you assigned to `result[right]` at that point? It looks uninitialized to me.

Comment: Also, avoid magic numbers like `52`. Make it `size_t len = ('Z'-'A' + 1) * 2;` and use `len` instead. Another detail: Since you return a pointer to this array, perhaps you should null terminate the array just in case it's meant to be printed?

Comment: How many times do you write to each location in result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my answer

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* problem58()
{
    int n = 0;
    int left = 0, right = 52 - 1;

    // A--->Z and Z--->A total number is 52, because string end with '\0'(0), so add 1 is 53.
    char* result = (char*)malloc(53 * sizeof(char));

    // Check if it is possible to dynamically allocate memory for 53 variables of type "char"
    // You can also write like this: if(result == NULL)
    if(NULL == result){
        printf("No space\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Initial result with 0,because string end with ('\0')0.
    // So result[0] will be 0, result[1] will be 0 ...... result[52] will be 0
    for(int m = 0; m < 53;m++){
        result[m] = 0;
    }

    for (char i = 'A'; i <= 'Z'; i++)
    {
        result[left] = i;
        //printf("%c", i);
        left++;
    }

    // Now left is 26, reset it to 0, because result[0] is 'A'
    left = 0;

    // n is execute times, need to let result[51] = result[0] = 'A', and result[50] = result[1] = 'B' ......
    //so right-- and left++
    for (n = 0; n < 26; n++)
    {
        result[right] = result[left];
        right--;
        left++;
    }
    return result;
}

int main()
{

    char* str = problem58();
    printf("str's length is %ld\n",strlen(str));
    printf("%s\n",str);
    free(str);
    return 0;
}
```

Run it will output

```
str's length is 52
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
```

Comment: Code without explanation is not a good answer.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I have changed my answer that add comment. Thank you for your point 
 out.

Comment: @Whozcry thanks for answering. but in code block `if(NULL == result)` i dont understand that, and code block `for(; m < 53;m++){` i dont understand. Can you explain it for me?

Comment: @Dinosour I have updated my answer that add more comment.

Answer (score -1):

This for loop

```
for (int i = left; i < right; i++)
{
    temp = result[left];
    result[left] = result[right];
    //..
```

invokes undefined behavior because the dynamically allocated array was not initialized and as a result the expressions `result[left]` and  `result[right]` have indeterminate values.  There is nothing to swap in the array. The array has to be filled with characters.

Also the array in any case does not contain a string because it is not appended with the terminating zero character `'\0';`.

If I have understood the assignment correctly then you need something like the following. Pay attention to that the function can be implemented in different ways.

For example

```
char * problem58( void )
{
    char *s = malloc( 2 * ( 'Z' - 'A' + 1 ) + 1 );

    if ( s != NULL )
    {
        char *p = s;
        char c = 'A';

        do
        {
            *p++ = c;
        } while ( c++ != 'Z' );

        while ( c != 'A' )
        {
            *p++ = --c;
        }

        *p = '\0';
    }

    return s;
}
```

or

```
char * problem58( void )
{
    size_t n = 2 * ( 'Z' - 'A' + 1 );

    char *s = malloc( n + 1 );

    if (s != NULL)
    {
        char *first = s, *last = s + n;

        *last = '\0';

        char c = 'A';

        do
        {
            *first++ = *--last = c;
        } while (c++ != 'Z');
    }

    return s;
}
```

And the function is called in main like

```
char *s = problem58();

if ( s != NULL ) puts( s );

free( s );
```

The expected output of a call of the function is

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
```

Comment: Re “invokes undefined behavior because… indeterminate values”: Using indeterminate values does not, by itself, cause undefined behavior. They are different things with different consequences.

Comment: @EricPostpischil From the C Standard "1 undefined behavior
behavior, upon use of a nonportable or erroneous program construct or of erroneous data,
for which this International Standard imposes no requirements"

Comment: That is from Annex J.2, which is a non-normative summary (it is not part of the official standard). It is incorrect on this point; the normative text (which is the official standard) does not make use of indeterminate values undefined behavior.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Relative to building the string his function has undefined behavior because it uses erroneous data. For example the function can build the expected string if the memory used by the allocated array already contains required data.

Comment: @EricPostpischil And the quote I provided defines the general notion of undefined behavior.